# Can Firebase map the following data model (multiple range inputs)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I haven’t done much data mapping in noSQL technologies. Therefore, I need help building a certain view of my use case.

In my App a user can create posts and attach certain data as a range of numbers. Let’s say the field is called duration and a user can input 3 to 5 hours. I am storing this data as maxDuration and minDuration to bypass the use of an array. Also I have multiple range inputs.
In another part of the app, the user can filter the posts - also with values in a range. Since Firebase does not allow multiple inequality filters I cannot filter data from my posts collection without filtering in the frontend.

Is there a way to be able to filter the data (e.g. a compound index) to not have to filter data in the frontend? Or to create another collection or view to make the queries more efficient?

Comment: Is it possible to aggregate the data? like instead of saving hours, minutes, etc turn it into unixtime or by appending or is it too much stuff thats unrelated and you really want to separate everything

Comment: The data is unrelated. Fore example one range input is duration (in hours) and one range input is budget (in €).

Comment: what i would do if i was really desperate would be to encode the data in a single field so you can search more efficiently over it

For example minHours+1000*maxHours